# Error with MySQL update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I dont now why it not work. I have tried'integer' for Now() too.

```
    $update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter  SET lastlogin=? WHERE id=?';
    $eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
    $eintrag->bind_param( 'si', NOW(), $id );
    $eintrag->execute();
```

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: Yes. PHP and MySQL have just stopped working. No one knows why.

Comment: You should trun php error on and better set error_report to E_ALL, an error message can great helpful to find your code problem.

Comment: Why was this voted to close as "too broad" ? Somebody's desperately looking for hats or what ?

Comment: @dystroy I didn't vote, but I assume it would because of the title of the question. not based upon the content.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel I would have fixed the title but somebody with low rep made a trivial edit, probably also for hats ^^

Comment: What I don't understand is why do people post the same answer?? majority are just a clone of @dystroy's answer

Comment: @SecretSquirrel For the points from upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now()` does not exist as a function in PHP.

Probably you have the PHP setting `display_errors` disabled. If you would have this setting on, you would see:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function now()
```

`NOW()` is a function in MySQL, which has an equivalent in PHP called `date()`.

Either do:

```
$update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter  SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE id=?';
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
$eintrag->bind_param( 'i', $id );
$eintrag->execute();
```

Or:

```
$update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter  SET lastlogin=? WHERE id=?';
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
$eintrag->bind_param( 'si', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $id );
$eintrag->execute();
```

Answer (score 8):

`NOW()` is a mysql function, not a PHP one. You might do

```
$update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE id=?';
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
$eintrag->bind_param( 'i', $id );
$eintrag->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I always have problem with bind_param, instead use bindValue().
But even if we say use bind_param, it should be bindParam() is it?

```
$update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE id=?';
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
$eintrag->bindValue( 'i', $id );
$eintrag->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question fails at that `NOW()` function part. It's mysqls not phps. To do it in php, here's example:

```
$update = 'UPDATE mitarbeiter SET lastlogin=? WHERE id=?';
$eintrag = $db->prepare( $update );
$eintrag->bind_param( 'i', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $id );
$eintrag->execute();
```